# How to format json so I can parse floats and strings

Tags: python, json

I am getting the error when I try to run the following code. I know it has something to do with the formating of the json file but I am not sure how to proceed/change in order to be able to get floats from the json file

```
print(location['latitude'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

my code

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.parse
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import re




url='https://www.vrbo.com/el-gr/%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%AC%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%82-%CE%B5%CE%BE%CE%BF%CF%87%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8E%CE%BD-%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B9%CF%8E%CE%BD/p436144?adultsCount=2&arrival=2021-05-08&departure=2021-05-16'
req = requests.get(url).text

search = re.search(r'window\.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ({.*});', req).group(1)

data = json.loads(search)


# print(data.keys())

# print(json_object)

for location in data['listingReducer']['geoCode']:
    print(location['latitude'])
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
`location` is presumably a string. You cant access string indices like you do dict elements.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `data['listingReducer']['geoCode']` to be a _list_ of dictionaries, but it isn't -- it's a _single_ dictionary.  Iterating over a dict yields the keys, which in this case are the strings `exact`, `latitude`, and `longitude`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data['listingReducer']['geoCode']` is a `dict` so doing `for location in data['listingReducer']['geoCode']`gives you the `keys`

```py
.
.
.
# print(data.keys())

# print(json_object)

# for location in data['listingReducer']['geoCode']:
#     print(location['latitude'])
print(data['listingReducer']['geoCode']['latitude'])
```

Comment: Nice that got what I wanted. Question: This is not my case for now but let's say that I wanted to extract more that one latitudes. How would I go about that?

Comment: It depends on the structure of your data. If it is list you need to index, if it is dict you need to get items with key.

Answer (score 2):

I need to see the JSON to verify but Python is considering your iterator object 'location' to be a string object. Therefore when you tried to obtain the 'latitude' object from location this error was given as strings can be indexed as well but those indices need to be integers. This would imply that the object at the JSON based location :data.listingReducer.geoCode.*whatever this is* is an actual value not another json object, and that value being some string.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access data in wrong way.

```
(Pdb) data['listingReducer']['geoCode']
{'exact': True, 'latitude': 35.489188293343325, 'longitude': 23.852005004882812}
```

So when you are trying to iterate through dict - you are iterating through keys of dict. In first iteration you are trying to do something like that:

```py
'exact'['location']
```

Probably you don't want to iterate through `geoCode`.
If you want to print out any of values of this dict - you should do for example:

```py
print(data['listingReducer']['geoCode']['latitude'])
```